# Initialising vector in C++

Tags: c++, list-initialization

I'm initialising vector using the below method

```
vector<int> num1{1, 9, 3, 7, 0, 7, 7, 2, 1};
```

and it is throwing error as below,

```
Multiplication.cpp:29:18: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        vector<int> num1{1, 9, 3, 7, 0, 7, 7, 2, 1};
                        ^
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Also, exactly what compiler, compiler version are you using?

Comment: Did you mean to write `vector<int>` perhaps?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is it capable of compiling C++11 code?

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp` try this

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's a compiler problem

Comment: Hi, check if you have `#include<vector>` and if you're not using `using namespace std;` to use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the vector library,
just add

```
#include<vector>
```

at the top of your code

it is running check [here](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/421421)

if you did that too, then too,
it is a compiler problem, try using a different complier or online complier like ideone